# PHP auto share to facebook page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have a php script to share automatically on FB page.  Everything worked perfectly until last night.  Now the post appears like a post on the page wall using my personal account.  Has something changed on facebook graph?

Comment: Redo sentence breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revise that your api key was not removed or modified. As well make sure you are using the actual page id or page api key (fb admin id) and not your profile's. The most common thing is that before last night you were logged on as your page and not your profile, then when you switched back it did so also. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thx for your answer the problem was that the access page access token was expired